# jquery hide checkbox and textbox if text box has a specific text

Tags: jquery, checkbox, textbox

i have these inputs:

```
<p class='zero'> <? echo $row['perigrafh10']?><input id='zeroin' type ='Text' value ='<? echo $row['poso10']?>' name='poso10'><input class='check' id='check' type='checkbox' <? if ($row['poso10_check'] >=1) {echo 'checked="checked"';}; ?> name='check_list[]' value='<? echo $row['poso10_check']?>' /></p>
<p class='zero'> <? echo $row['perigrafh11']?><input id='zeroin' type ='Text' value ='<? echo $row['poso11']?>' name='poso11'><input class='check' id='check' type='checkbox' <? if ($row['poso11_check'] >=1) {echo 'checked="checked"';}; ?> name='check_list[]' value='<? echo $row['poso11_check']?>' /></p>
....
```

what i want to achieve is to hide the  textbox and the checkbox if the textbox text is 0.00.

i can hide the textbox without issues using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('input:text').each(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 0.00){
   $(this).hide();
       }
    }
   );
 </script>
```

but i have no luck to hide the checkboxes too. What code do i need? i ve done several tests but couldnt find solution. i m using latest jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to hide the entire `<p>` element

```
$(this).closest(".zero").hide();
```

Comment: iGanja it worked like a charm. Something deep down in me was saying to hide the whole p element but never tried. Thanks

Comment: @Stathis accept this answer if it solved your problem. As a side note, I believe .parent() instead of .closest(".zero") could also work well in this example.

Comment: yes, .parent() would work in this case. I like using .closest() so I never have to worry about inserting a parent container later and then everything breaking.